# How to change URL color in TJvRichEdit?

Tags: delphi, richedit, delphi-xe8, jvcl

In `TJvRichEdit` Version 3.48 (from **JVCL**) there is an `AutoURLDetect` property:

[image]

The URLs have a dark blue color which makes them difficult to read on a dark background:

[image]

I use `TJvRichEdit` in a VCL Form application in Delphi XE8.

So how can I change the URL color to a lighter blue color both at design-time or at run-time?

Comment: The underlying Windows control doesn't support custom link colors unless it's a ["friendly name" link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks.aspx), in which case you specify the friendly text and formatting yourself. On the other hand, if the automatic colors are too similar, the control already has logic to adjust them automatically: Check out [Murray Sargent's article on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2015/06/08/autolink-color-contrast.aspx).